# white space between toolbar and status bar

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar

[image]

Just so know the listview in the image is fragment generated. But i dont think that should interfere with toolbar's layout. Here is the code for layout -

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_songlistview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/croctooth"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
    tools:context="com.shaikhsakib.sounddemo.SongActivity">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentSongListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar2" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here the the corresponding activity to the above layout -

```
    package com.shaikhsakib.sounddemo;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class SongActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_song);

        loadFragment();
        Toolbar toolbar2 = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar2);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar2);

    }

    private void loadFragment() {
// create a FragmentManager
        FragmentManager fm;
        fm = getFragmentManager();
// create a FragmentTransaction to begin the transaction and replace the Fragment
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
// replace the FrameLayout with new Fragment
        SongListFragment slv = new SongListFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.songFrameLayout, slv);
        fragmentTransaction.commit(); // save the changes
    }
}
```

I checked most of the white space toolbar related answers on Stack Overflow but nothing works. Maybe my problem is different.

**EDIT 1**

Here is my Main Activity. It also loads a fragment listview an ha custom toolbar. But no such whitespace here -

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    loadFragment();
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

}

private void loadFragment() {
// create a FragmentManager
        FragmentManager fm;
        fm = getFragmentManager();
// create a FragmentTransaction to begin the transaction and replace the Fragment
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
// replace the FrameLayout with new Fragment
        PLayListFragment flv = new PLayListFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, flv);
        fragmentTransaction.commit(); // save the changes
    }
}
```

Also notice that I am replacing the same R.id.frameLayout in both the activities but that should not have anything to do with toolbar. Can anybody tell why its not happening in MainActivity but in other activity.

Comment: whats the color of `croctooth` is it that greyish color ?

Comment: Please share your **main activity layout**.

Comment: make relative layout to linear layout

Comment: Try to remove "android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"". I think it might be the reason for that. @sakib

Comment: yes croctooth is light greyish color. Have put main activity. No relative layput is not solving the problem and neither is removing android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize solving it.

Comment: Remove there both
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

Comment: @AndroidTeam removing android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" does not sove the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was not actually with Toolbar but with Status bar. It needed     CoordinatorLayout instead of RelativeLayout as parent. So all i had to do was make the relative layout as child of CoordinatorLayout and pass an attribute like     android:fitsSystemWindows="true". That solved the problem.

Here is the solution -

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/croctooth"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
    tools:context="com.shaikhsakib.sounddemo.SongActivity">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentSongListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar2" />


</RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```